# Question on the use of a parametric version of Transfinite Recursion Theorem in Introduction to Set Theory 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, recursion, transfinite-recursion

My question concerns a proof given on page 118 in the text Introduction to Set Theory 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech.

The authors on page 117 prove a version of the transfinite recursion theorem (Theorem 4.11) that says given unary operations $G_1, G_2$, and $G_3$ there is an operation $F$ such that 
\begin{align*}
 &F(0)=G_1(0),\\
 &F(\alpha+1)=G_2(F(\alpha))\quad\text{for all ordinals $\alpha$, and}\\
 &F(\alpha)=G_3(F_\restriction \alpha)\quad\text{for all limit ordinals $\alpha$}.\\
\end{align*}

They then leave it up to the reader to devise a parametric version of Theorem 4.11.
I have determined this to be as follows: Given binary operations $G_1, G_2$, and $G_3$ there is an operation $F$ such that for all z

\begin{align*}
 &F(z,0)=G_1(z,0),\\
 &F(z,\alpha+1)=G_2(z,F_z(\alpha))\quad\text{for all ordinals $\alpha$, and}\\
 &F(z,\alpha)=G_3(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)\quad\text{for all limit ordinals $\alpha$}.\\
\end{align*}

Next they make use of the parametric version of Theorem 4.11 in the proof of Theorem 3.6 on page 118. 
Theorem 3.6 states:

\begin{align*}
&\text{Let G be an operation.}\\
&\text{For any set $a$ there is a unique infinite sequence $\langle a_n|n\in N \rangle$ such that} \\
&(a) a_0=a\\
&(b) a_{n+1}=G(a_n,n)\quad\text{for all $n\in N$}\\
\end{align*}

The proof for Theorem 3.6 given in the text is as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\text{Let G be an operation. We want to find, for every set $a$, a sequence}\\
&\text{$\langle a_n|n\in N \rangle$ such that $a_0=a$ and $a_{n+1}=G(a_n,n)$ for all $n\in N.$}\\
&\text{By the parametric version of the Transfinite Recursion Theorem 4.11,}\\
&\text{there is an operation $F$ such that $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1)=G(F(n),n)$ for all $n\in N.$}\\
&\text{Now we apply the Axiom of Replacement: There exists a sequence $\langle a_n|n\in N \rangle$}\\
&\text{that is equal to $F\restriction \omega$ amd the Theorem follows.}\\
\end{align*}

Now, I understand everything in the proof of Theorem 3.6 except how the parametric version of Theorem 4.11 is used to derive the operation $F$ in the proof. Can can someone please help me fill in blanks?

Comment: I thought this was going to be an easy question for someone.

Comment: I'd suggest that you haven't received any help because the nature of your question requires that you find someone who's read Jech recently. In Googling for parameterized transfinite recursion, two of the first three results are your question and Jech's book. I'd suggest explaining the notion of parameterization for those who are interested enough to answer but not interested enough to pull out our Jech.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that the Theorem to be proved should be stated a bit more precisely as

> Given any operation $G$ and any $a$ there is a unique infinite sequence $\langle a_n : n \in \omega \rangle$ such that
>
> 1. $a_0 = a$; and
> 2. $a_{n+1} = G ( a_n )$.

I do not think that the *parametrized* version of transfinite recursion is needed (and the authors do not appear to actually use it).  Indeed, given $G$ and $a$ define the following three operations:

- $G_1 ( x ) = a$;
- $G_2 ( x ) = G ( x )$; and
- $G_3 ( x ) = a$.

(Note that as the result does not depend on the value of our operation at an infinite ordinal, the operation $G_3$ may be chosen arbitrarily.)  Then by the theorem on transfinite recursion there is a unique operation $F$ such that

- $F(0) = G_1(0) = a$;
- $F(\alpha+1) = G_2 ( F ( \alpha) ) = G ( F ( \alpha) )$; and
- $F(\alpha) = G_3 ( F \restriction \alpha ) = a$ for limit ordinals $\alpha > 0$.

Then the sequence $F \restriction \omega = \langle F(n) : n \in \omega \rangle$ will be as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think Hrbacek and Jech stated Theorem 3.6 as such to mirror the recursion theorem given earlier in the text (pg. 47) for the natural numbers. As stated in the text they want to show how the earlier results for natural numbers generalize to ordinal numbers.