# recursion theorem set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Somhow I am having trubbles understanding this theorem..
for example, In this link,
[Question on the use of a parametric version of Transfinite Recursion Theorem in Introduction to Set Theory 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215444/question-on-the-use-of-a-parametric-version-of-transfinite-recursion-theorem-in)

it is stated by Arthur Fischer that:

Given any operation G and any $a$ there is a unique infinite sequence $a_n:n∈ω$ such that:
$a_0=a$; and $a_{n+1}=G(a_n)$

I don't understand, how can something like that be stated. for example, define $G(n)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n$. So, for every $n \in N$, $G(n)=\omega$.

and $\omega$ is not an infinite sequence..

It is strange, since I do have experience in understanding mathematical definitions.. and here.. something doesn't work for me..... :(

any help?

Thanks!
Shir

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, I wonder what you meant by defining your $G(n)$ in such a strange way:$$G(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n.$$Since, as you point out, the limit on the right is $\omega$, why not just write $G(n)=\omega$ as your definition of $G(n)$?

Next, I don't see why you think there is a problem with finding an infinite sequence $a_n:n\in\omega$ such that $a_0=a$ and $a_{n+1}=G(a_n)$. The (unique) solution, of course, is: $a_0=a,\;a_1=\omega,\;a_2=\omega$, etc.; i.e., the sequence is $$a,\;\omega,\;\omega,\;\omega,\dots,\omega,\dots.$$Sure, $\omega$ isn't an infinite sequence; so what, neither is $a$ as far as we know. In general, the **terms** of an infinite sequence do not have to be infinite sequences.

Comment: I will think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$G(n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n$ has no mathematical meaning, since $n$ occurs as a free variable on the left-hand side, but a bound variable on the right-hand side.  It's like saying "Let $k$ be the sum of all values of $k$."

More to the point, $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is not an *operation* in the same sense that, say $x\mapsto x^2$ is an operation.  The latter can take a number and return a number, but the former takes a whole sequence, and returns a number (well, when it even exists).

So you can't really build a sequence from your "operation" in the way you seem to think.  Let's try it.  $a_0 = 1$.  $a_1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 =$... well, $1$ seems to be the answer.  And $a_2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$, $a_3=\ldots$, and so forth.

In other words, saying that you are building a sequence by writing $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ is cheating; you assume that you have an infinite sequence $a_n = n$, then you take its limit, and then you say that there is no infinite sequence.  But without having an infinite sequence in the first place, what are you taking the limit of?

On the other hand, if you write $G(n) = n+1$, and $a_0 = 0$, then Fischer is quite right: there is a unique infinite sequence that we get by repeatedly applying $G$.  $a_1 = G(0) = 0+1 = 1$, $a_2 = G(1) = 1+1 = 2$, and so on; in fact, $a_n = n$.

Comment: I will think about it. Thank you!